# How to pick a solution when there are infinitely many

Tags: geometry, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system

So I am studying this particular set of equations $$x+y+z=2$$

$$x^2+y^2+z^2+2xy=1$$

which can be combined to make

$$2x^2+2y^2+2z^2+4xy-x-y-z=0$$

Putting this into Wolfram gives me an infinite elliptic cylinder

[image]

This was to be expected, of course, since the system is underdetermined. However, I now want to pick a point $(x,y,z)$ from off the surface. My questions are

1. In a situation like this, is there a notion of a best point under some criterion?
2. Further, how would one even go about picking a point? I'm worried that just choosing numbers randomly might land me in a situation akin to $x^2+y^2=0$, where if I chose, for example, $y=1$ by chance, then $x$ would be complex, which is not desirable in this case.
3. Finally, could the proposed method be extended to surfaces in $\mathcal{R}^n$?

I have already tried combing through the internet and this site, but I could only find a solution if the object was a sphere, not an elliptic cylinder. Any help or resources would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Whenever a system is underdetermined, I generally pick some cost function, and pick a point that minimizes that cost function over that system.

Comment: To add to @DonThousand answer, the "best point criterion" is completely determined by your cost function. Cost functions allow you to measure a distance from your chosen result to your ideal result. Maybe you want $x$ close to $y$, maybe you want $x$ far from $y$, maybe you want to minimize the norm of $(x,y)$, maybe you want to maximize it, maybe you want the values closest to norm $1$; etc, etc. This is all encoded in your choice of cost function. Note that generally there are multiple local extrema to pick a solution from.

Comment: Set $w=x+y$ and sole a system in two variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a comment, but it's too long to fit in a comment box.

The first thing you should know is that, while your third equation is derived from the previous two equations, and thus contains all the solutions to your system, it is not equivalent to your previous two equations (i.e. it contains a lot more solutions).

Instead, consider that
$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 2xy = 1 \iff (x + y)^2 + z^2 = 1.$$
Let $w = x + y$. Then our system becomes
$$\begin{cases} w + z = 2 \\ w^2 + z^2 = 1.\end{cases}$$
Unfortunately, this system has no solution. There are multiple ways to show this, but probably the most elementary method is to substitute $z = 2 - w$ into the second equation:
$$w^2 + (2 - w)^2 = 1 \iff 2w^2 - 2w + 1 = 0,$$
a quadratic with negative discriminant. Thus, no real solutions exist.

So, your first two questions are moot.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, more research is needed.
$$
\begin{align*}
x + y + z &= 2 \tag{1}\\
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 2xy &= 1 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
$$
Consider eq.(1)
$$
(x + y + z)^2 = 2^2
$$
$$
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 2xy + 2yz + 2 zx = 4 \tag{3}
$$
Now subtract the eq.(2)
$$
2yz + 2 zx = 3 \tag{4}
$$
Subtract twice eq.(4) from eq.(3)
$$
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 2xy - 2yz - 2 zx = -2
$$
$$
(-x - y + z)^2 = -2.
$$
The latter means there is no real solution to the system of equations (1) and (2).